Identify post apocalyptic American movie from 80s, mostly set in desert like enviroment
Last seen on tv as a child in late 80 or early 90s.
Only clue i have is that its a bunch of people traveling in a desert like environment looking for survivors and scavenging food.
Once scene is in one empty city (seems like arizona/texas) and go into some mall and gets surrounded by cockroaches but escape in their vehicle.
Otherwise its mostly in the car traveling.
Cant remember how the movie begins or ends.

Sounds like Damnation Alley (1977)
Plot includes desert environment, looking for survivors, a lot of car traveling (landmaster) and a mutated cockroaches-scene in Salt Lake City.

Denton has been considering going to Albany, New York to find the
  source of a lone radio transmission. He and the remaining others set
  out in two Air Force "Landmasters," giant 12-wheeled armored personnel
  carriers capable of climbing 60-degree inclines and operating in
  water. They must cross "Damnation Alley," considered "the path of
  least resistance" between intense radiation areas thus named by
  Denton. Along their journey one of the Landmasters becomes disabled in
  a storm (which also kills Perry) and they encounter mutated "flesh
  stripping cockroaches" in the ruins of Salt Lake City which eat Keegan
  alive. Denton and Tanner also pick up two survivors: a woman in Las
  Vegas, Janice (Dominique Sanda), and a teenage boy, Billy (Jackie
  Earle Haley), discovered in an abandoned house. Later they fight off a
  band of crazed gun-toting mountain men they encounter in the ruins of
  a gas station. Denton uses a rocket launcher to destroy the gas
  station.
As they continue their journey, the Landmaster develops a problem with
  its drivetrain and they head to Detroit. Denton comments that it was
  "designed to use spare truck parts", semi-trucks in particular. In
  Detroit they enter a large wrecking yard in search of the needed
  parts. A large storm comes upon the group and they take shelter in
  their vehicle just as a tidal wave washes them away. After the storm
  passes, they are adrift in a large body of water and it appears that
  the Earth has returned to its normal axis as the sky is clear. Using
  the Landmaster's amphibious capability, they reach land. As they are
  making repairs, they hear a radio broadcast of music and an attempt to
  reach survivors. After making contact, Tanner and Billy set out on to
  locate the source of the broadcast

Cockroach scene is available on youtube:



